# MonetDB + JDBC "no such database"

Tags: jdbc, monetdb

So I'm working on getting MonetDB hooked up with JDBC but am having issues even with the basic tutorial. I'm probably doing something wrong here and maybe someone could point me in the right direction (that would be greatly appreciated!).

So the commands I'm running are:

```
monetdbd start /dbfarm
monetdb create test1
monetdb release test1
java -jar /jars/jdbcclient.jar -u monetdb -d test1

password:
Database connect failed: no such database 'test1', please create first
```

--

This seems odd to me because I can access test1 via mclient -u monetdb -d test1.

TIA

Comment: Would you mind adding the output of the commands that you entered?

Comment: The output for the command is: Database connect failed: no such database 'test1', please create first

Comment: It might be only missing in the snipped above, but it seems you forgot to start 'test1', e.g. `monetdb start test1`. This action is separate from starting the `dbfarm` with `monetdbd` and creating a releasing the database with `monetdb`.